# What is the simplest RTF editor in linux?

Tags: linux, rtf

All I need is a simple text editor that is able to do simple formatting (bold, italic, underline, list).

Given my situation, what is the best solution for editing RTF in linux?

Comment: Have you found a CLI editor that handles RTF?

Comment: Maybe [FocusWriter](http://gottcode.org/focuswriter/) with basic RTF will meet your needs.

Comment: The world has changed since this question was asked in 2009, so probably the simplest solution now for adding formatting to plain text would be to use Mark down. Many text editors such as Kate, included with Fedora will format Mark down.

Comment: @JasonS MarkDowning is not as simple as using an GUI RTF editor. In practical, we want to take notes or write some things **fast** and we dont want the hassle of using markdowns. Is `Ctrl + B` faster or using `**`??

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as off-topic? It seems like the perfect use-case for superuser: requesting links to software that solves a particular problem on a particular system?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try [AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/).

Comment: meh, it's still too overkill for my needs

Comment: hmm.. on second though, I can hide most of it's UI (toolbars, statusbar, etc). I can use abiword for simple RTF editing and oowriter for heavy editing. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Don't forget that wine provides Wordpad by default. First install wine and then type the following in a terminal:

```
wine wordpad
```

Comment: Thanks, no additional dependencies, exactly what I needed.

Comment: Should be accepted imho

Answer (score 5):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) Writer can be used on rtf files. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice_Writer).

Answer (score 4):

For the CLI use catdoc. Since this is superuser.com I'm assuming you know how to install it. For a GUI approach I know LibreOffice can view .rtf, but I also think Abiword will work.

Comment: *Alone in the world was a little CatDoc*

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Ted](http://www.nllgg.nl/Ted/) would be an appropriate choice in that case.

However, I am curious as to know what your usecase is for using RTF (instead of, say, HTML with a plain text editor)

Comment: Wikipedia link (don't forget to add the trailing ")") http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_(word_processor)

Comment: Hi, I've tried Ted before. But, it's buggy. My usecase is, I sometime edit my notes on windows, which is easy using wordpad.

Comment: Ted isn't in Ubuntu at the moment, and the .deb package depends on an old version of libtiff and crashes on startup on ubuntu 14.04.  I did not try building from source.

Comment: My use case (years later) is trying to apply for a job and they accept .doc, rtf, txt, and html (and then it says upon upload it doesn't take html.)  Grrr.  Doesn't accept pdf.